# How does CSS style affect a base HTML template when extending it?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a base CSS and HTML:

```css
.row{
padding: 100px
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
</div>
```

and I extend that in another template

```css
/* another_template.hml */

.row{
padding: 50px
  
}
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

<div class="row">
  <p> Some text </p>
</div>
{% block content %}
```

Is the padding of the two rows different or equal? E.g does HTML overwrite the row-property first (from 100px to 50px) and apply that to everything in `another_template.html` or does it give `another_template.html` a padding of 100px and keep the padding *inside* of `another_template` 50px?

TL;DR - how does CSS properties inherit when extending HTML?

Comment: It doesn't matter your templating language or any backend code, whatever gets to the client side it gets processed as it should be - The CSS you write after your initial  CSS styling will overwrite it.